# Artifactory change docker image tag inside one repo

Tags: artifactory, docker-image

I want to change the tags from my docker images in Artifactory using the REST API. The only possible way to make this work I could find out is to promote the image to an other repository and promote it back while changing the tag.

I really don't want to create an other repository only to move my image there and afterwards back.

When I tried to promote the image to the source repository I get this error message:

```
{\n  "errors" : [ {\n    "status" : 400,\n    "message" : "Skipping promote since destination and source are the same"\n  } ]\n}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround. They way you do it is to use Copy Item and delete it afterwards.

```
 POST /api/copy/{srcRepoKey}/{srcFilePath}?to=/{targetRepoKey}/{targetFilePath}[&dry=1][&suppressLayouts=0/1(default)][&failFast=0/1]
```

[Link to the docu](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/copy-item)

I don't understand why they don't list this information next to the documentation of promoting an image. In general the new Artifactory documentation is really bad. I don't like it and hope they revert it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to [promote a Docker image](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/docker-registry#:%7E:text=Proxy%20Settings.-,Promoting%20Docker%20Images,-Artifactory%20supports%20promoting) as you mentioned in the question.
In this case the image will be moved/promoted and the properties for that image (e.g can be found in the UI when clicking on the manifest.json) will be changed with it accordingly.

Another option, similar to the one you found is with the [Move REST-API call](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/copy-item#:%7E:text=%E2%A7%89-,Move%20Item,-Description%3A%20Moves%20an) (instead of Copy) to change the image path (and with it the tag as it’s according to the path) and then **it will not be required** to have an additional action and also delete, for example:

```
$ curl -uadmin -XPOST "http://<Artifactory-URL>/artifactory/api/move/<Docker-Repo>/<Image-Name>/<Tag-Name>?to=/<Docker-Repo>/<Image-Name>/<New-Tag-Name>”
```

Note that in this case (both for move/copy) the properties (e.g the property for the tag name) will not be changed following that action), however, it will not affect the functionality and the Docker image can be pulled with the new tag according to the new path it was moved to.
That being said the properties can also be changed manually after the change if you’d like to keep the new path and properties aligned.

In addition, similar to the Move REST-API call, the move operation can also be done directly from Artifactory UI by right clicking on the image.

Of course there's also the option to Pull -> Re-Tag -> Push and delete the old image.